# Why this for loop always show 'o's.C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Here I have written a code that contains a struct (vectors). I've used a for loop display the data inside the structure. I think something is wrong with the for loop. Could you guys correct me out.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct coffee {
  string name;
  int itemprice;
  string country;
  int quantity;
};

float remainder, price2, price;

int main() {
  int coffeetype = 1;

  vector<coffee> coffee_drink(7);
  "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20;
  "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20;
  "Long black", 80, "Austral", 20;
  "Americano", 100, "America", 20;
  "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20;
  "Irishcoffee", 130, "Ireland", 20;
  "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20;

  cout << fixed;
  cout << setprecision(2);

  for (int i = 0; i != coffee_drink.size(); ++i)
    cout << "\n " << i + 1 << ") " << coffee_drink[i].name << "\t\t"
         << coffee_drink[i].itemprice << "\t\t" << coffee_drink[i].country
         << "\t\t(" << coffee_drink[i].quantity << ") remaining";
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `"Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 ;` would do anything with the vector? (A decent compiler should say "warning: statement has no effect", or something similar, quite a few times about your code.) Study examples more carefully.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> v1(7); "this"; "does"; "not"; "fill"; "vector"; "with"; "elements";` `std::vector<std::string> v2 = { "use", "list", "initialization", "instead", ":", "-", ")" };`

Comment: You had the correct code in your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use brace initializers to make it easier:

```
int main() {
   int coffeetype = 1;

   vector <coffee> coffee_drink =
   {{ "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
   {"Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20},
   {"Long black", 80, "Austral", 20},
   {"Americano", 100, "America", 20},
   {"Latte", 200, "Italy", 20},
   {"Irishcoffee", 130, "Ireland", 20},
   {"Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20}};

   cout << fixed;
   cout << setprecision(2);

   int i = 0;
   for (const auto & drink: coffee_drink)
      cout << "\n " << ++i << ") " << 
      drink.name << "\t\t" << 
      drink.itemprice << "\t\t" << 
      drink.country << "\t\t(" << 
      drink.quantity << ") remaining";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see your for loop is missing an enclosing bracket. But that is not the main issue. Two things you need to fix are:

1. you don't add any values to your vector. This can be done by using [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or at initialization with a [brace initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

```
vector <coffee> coffee_drink;
coffee_drink.push_back({"Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20});
coffee_drink.push_back({"Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 });
```

2.

```
for (int i = 0; i != coffee_drink.size(); ++i){
    cout << "\n " << i+1 << ") " << coffee_drink[i].name << "\t\t" << coffee_drink[i].itemprice << "\t\t" << coffee_drink[i].country << "\t\t(" << coffee_drink[i].quantity << ") remaining";
}
```

Comment: @AkibRhast I have edited your answer to make the code blocks whole and provide some explanation of your answers. Code is good but code with an explanation about the code makes it even better. Referencing some background information (such as cppreference) is also a good idea as it enables OP to learn further.

Comment: @TarickWelling Thanks a lot. Appreciate it! I am new, so sometimes struggle with the formatting!
"Referencing some background information (such as cppreference) is also a good idea as it enables OP to learn further."
Will keep in mind for next time!